# Applying displacement mapping and specular mapping

Tags: webgl, webgl2

I am trying to apply both displacement mapping and specular mapping for the earth and only displacement mapping for the moon.

I could transfer height map to normal map but if I use the same height map to apply displacement mapping, it does not work as I expected..

Here is the example image

[image: Example 1]

as you can see the bumpness around the earth and the moon but there are no actual height diffrences.

If I apply specular map to the earth, the earth becomes like this

[image: Example 2]

I want only the ocean of the earth to shine but my code turns the earth into the whole black, I can only see some white dots on the earth...

These textures are from this [site](http://planetpixelemporium.com/earth.html)

Here is my both vertex shader code and the fragment shader code

```
"use strict";
const loc_aPosition = 3;
const loc_aNormal = 5;
const loc_aTexture = 7;
const VSHADER_SOURCE =
`#version 300 es
layout(location=${loc_aPosition}) in vec4 aPosition;
layout(location=${loc_aNormal}) in vec4 aNormal;
layout(location=${loc_aTexture}) in vec2 aTexCoord;


uniform mat4 uMvpMatrix;
uniform mat4 uModelMatrix;    // Model matrix
uniform mat4 uNormalMatrix;   // Transformation matrix of the normal

uniform sampler2D earth_disp;
uniform sampler2D moon_disp;

//uniform float earth_dispScale;
//uniform float moon_dispScale;

//uniform float earth_dispBias;
//uniform float moon_dispBias;

uniform bool uEarth;
uniform bool uMoon;


out vec2 vTexCoord;
out vec3 vNormal;
out vec3 vPosition;


void main() 
{

  float disp;

  if(uEarth)
    disp = texture(earth_disp, aTexCoord).r; //Extracting the color information from the image
  else if(uMoon)
    disp = texture(moon_disp, aTexCoord).r; //Extracting the color information from the image

  vec4 displace = aPosition;

  float displaceFactor = 2.0;
  float displaceBias = 0.5;

  if(uEarth || uMoon) //Using Displacement Mapping
  {
    displace += (displaceFactor * disp - displaceBias) * aNormal;
    gl_Position = uMvpMatrix * displace;
  }
  else //Not using displacement mapping
    gl_Position = uMvpMatrix * aPosition;

  // Calculate the vertex position in the world coordinate
  vPosition = vec3(uModelMatrix * aPosition);

  vNormal = normalize(vec3(uNormalMatrix * aNormal));
  vTexCoord = aTexCoord;

}`;

// Fragment shader program
const FSHADER_SOURCE =
`#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

uniform vec3 uLightColor;     // Light color
uniform vec3 uLightPosition;  // Position of the light source
uniform vec3 uAmbientLight;   // Ambient light color

uniform sampler2D sun_color;
uniform sampler2D earth_color;
uniform sampler2D moon_color;

uniform sampler2D earth_bump;
uniform sampler2D moon_bump;

uniform sampler2D specularMap;


in vec3 vNormal;
in vec3 vPosition;
in vec2 vTexCoord;
out vec4 fColor;

uniform bool uIsSun;
uniform bool uIsEarth;
uniform bool uIsMoon;



vec2 dHdxy_fwd(sampler2D bumpMap, vec2 UV, float bumpScale)
{
    vec2 dSTdx  = dFdx( UV );
        vec2 dSTdy  = dFdy( UV );
        float Hll   = bumpScale * texture( bumpMap, UV ).x;
        float dBx   = bumpScale * texture( bumpMap, UV + dSTdx ).x - Hll;
        float dBy   = bumpScale * texture( bumpMap, UV + dSTdy ).x - Hll;
        return vec2( dBx, dBy );
}

vec3 pertubNormalArb(vec3 surf_pos, vec3 surf_norm, vec2 dHdxy)
{
    vec3 vSigmaX = vec3( dFdx( surf_pos.x ), dFdx( surf_pos.y ), dFdx( surf_pos.z ) );
        vec3 vSigmaY = vec3( dFdy( surf_pos.x ), dFdy( surf_pos.y ), dFdy( surf_pos.z ) );
        vec3 vN = surf_norm;        // normalized
        vec3 R1 = cross( vSigmaY, vN );
        vec3 R2 = cross( vN, vSigmaX );
        float fDet = dot( vSigmaX, R1 );
        fDet *= ( float( gl_FrontFacing ) * 2.0 - 1.0 );
        vec3 vGrad = sign( fDet ) * ( dHdxy.x * R1 + dHdxy.y * R2 );
        return normalize( abs( fDet ) * surf_norm - vGrad );
}



void main() 
{
    vec2 dHdxy;
    vec3 bumpNormal;
    float bumpness = 1.0;
    if(uIsSun)
      fColor = texture(sun_color, vTexCoord);
    else if(uIsEarth)
    {
      fColor = texture(earth_color, vTexCoord);
      dHdxy = dHdxy_fwd(earth_bump, vTexCoord, bumpness);
    }
    else if(uIsMoon)
    {
      fColor = texture(moon_color, vTexCoord);
      dHdxy = dHdxy_fwd(moon_bump, vTexCoord, bumpness);
    }



    // Normalize the normal because it is interpolated and not 1.0 in length any more
    vec3 normal = normalize(vNormal);


    // Calculate the light direction and make its length 1.
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(uLightPosition - vPosition);



    // The dot product of the light direction and the orientation of a surface (the normal)
    float nDotL;
    if(uIsSun)
      nDotL = 1.0;
    else
      nDotL = max(dot(lightDirection, normal), 0.0);



    // Calculate the final color from diffuse reflection and ambient reflection
    vec3 diffuse = uLightColor * fColor.rgb * nDotL;
    vec3 ambient = uAmbientLight * fColor.rgb;
    float specularFactor = texture(specularMap, vTexCoord).r; //Extracting the color information from the image




    vec3 diffuseBump;
    if(uIsEarth || uIsMoon)
    {
      bumpNormal = pertubNormalArb(vPosition, normal, dHdxy);
      diffuseBump = min(diffuse + dot(bumpNormal, lightDirection), 1.1);
    }

    vec3 specular = vec3(0.0);
    float shiness = 12.0;
    vec3 lightSpecular = vec3(1.0);

    if(uIsEarth && nDotL > 0.0)
    {
      vec3 v = normalize(-vPosition); // EyePosition
      vec3 r = reflect(-lightDirection, bumpNormal); // Reflect from the surface
      specular = lightSpecular * specularFactor * pow(dot(r, v), shiness);
    }

    //Update Final Color
    if(uIsEarth)
      fColor = vec4( (diffuse * diffuseBump * specular) + ambient, fColor.a); // Specular
    else if(uIsMoon)
      fColor = vec4( (diffuse * diffuseBump) + ambient, fColor.a);
    else if(uIsSun)
      fColor = vec4(diffuse + ambient, fColor.a);
}`;
```

Could you tell me where do I have to check?

Comment: Just a comment but it's not normal to put so many conditionals in a shader. Instead of `uIsEarth`, `uIsMoon`, `uIsSun` just a make a planet shader with no conditionals and change the inputs (the uniforms and textures) OR make 3 separate shaders, one for the Sun, one for the Earth, and one for the Moon if they really need to do different things.

Comment: Yes... that is true..  I tried to switch shaders but, it didn't work so well, this is the reason I put so many boolean variables in my code..

Comment: PS: I double checked the displacement and found an issue. updated the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it was me I'd first strip the shader down the simplest thing and see if I get what I want. You want a specular shine so do you get a specular shine with only specular calculations in your shaders

Trimming your shaders to just draw a flat phong shading didn't produce the correct results

This line

```
fColor = vec4( (diffuse * specular) + ambient, fColor.a);
```

needed to be

```
fColor = vec4( (diffuse + specular) + ambient, fColor.a);
```

You add the specular, not multiply by it.

```js
"use strict";
const loc_aPosition = 3;
const loc_aNormal = 5;
const loc_aTexture = 7;
const VSHADER_SOURCE =
`#version 300 es
layout(location=${loc_aPosition}) in vec4 aPosition;
layout(location=${loc_aNormal}) in vec4 aNormal;


uniform mat4 uMvpMatrix;
uniform mat4 uModelMatrix;    // Model matrix
uniform mat4 uNormalMatrix;   // Transformation matrix of the normal

out vec3 vNormal;
out vec3 vPosition;


void main() 
{
  gl_Position = uMvpMatrix * aPosition;

  // Calculate the vertex position in the world coordinate
  vPosition = vec3(uModelMatrix * aPosition);

  vNormal = normalize(vec3(uNormalMatrix * aNormal));
}`;

// Fragment shader program
const FSHADER_SOURCE =
`#version 300 es
precision highp float;

uniform vec3 uLightColor;     // Light color
uniform vec3 uLightPosition;  // Position of the light source
uniform vec3 uAmbientLight;   // Ambient light color

in vec3 vNormal;
in vec3 vPosition;
out vec4 fColor;

void main() 
{
    vec2 dHdxy;
    vec3 bumpNormal;
    float bumpness = 1.0;
    
    fColor = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 1, 1);

    // Normalize the normal because it is interpolated and not 1.0 in length any more
    vec3 normal = normalize(vNormal);

    // Calculate the light direction and make its length 1.
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(uLightPosition - vPosition);

    // The dot product of the light direction and the orientation of a surface (the normal)
    float nDotL;
    nDotL = max(dot(lightDirection, normal), 0.0);

    // Calculate the final color from diffuse reflection and ambient reflection
    vec3 diffuse = uLightColor * fColor.rgb * nDotL;
    vec3 ambient = uAmbientLight * fColor.rgb;
    float specularFactor = 1.0;

    bumpNormal = normal;
    vec3 specular = vec3(0.0);
    float shiness = 12.0;
    vec3 lightSpecular = vec3(1.0);

    vec3 v = normalize(-vPosition); // EyePosition
    vec3 r = reflect(-lightDirection, bumpNormal); // Reflect from the surface
    specular = lightSpecular * specularFactor * pow(dot(r, v), shiness);

    fColor = vec4( (diffuse + specular) + ambient, fColor.a); // Specular
}`;

function main() {
  const m4 = twgl.m4;
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
  if (!gl) { return alert('need webgl2'); }

  const prgInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE]);
  const verts = twgl.primitives.createSphereVertices(1, 40, 40);
  // calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each array
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
    aPosition: verts.position,
    aNormal: verts.normal,
    aTexCoord: verts.texcoord,
    indices: verts.indices,
  });
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer for each attribute
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, prgInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  
  gl.useProgram(prgInfo.program);
    
  const fov = 60 * Math.PI / 180;
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 20.0;
  const mat = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, near, far);
  m4.translate(mat, [0, 0, -3], mat);
  
  // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniform
  twgl.setUniforms(prgInfo, {
    uMvpMatrix: mat,
    uModelMatrix: m4.identity(),    // Model matrix
    uNormalMatrix: m4.identity(),   // Transformation matrix of the normal
    uLightColor: [1, 1, 1],     // Light color
    uLightPosition: [2, 2, 10], // Position of the light source
    uAmbientLight: [0, 0, 0],   // Ambient light color
  });
  
  // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
}
main();
```

```css
body { margin: 0 }
canvas { display: block; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

So now we can add in the specular map

```js
"use strict";
const loc_aPosition = 3;
const loc_aNormal = 5;
const loc_aTexCoord = 7;
const VSHADER_SOURCE =
`#version 300 es
layout(location=${loc_aPosition}) in vec4 aPosition;
layout(location=${loc_aNormal}) in vec4 aNormal;
layout(location=${loc_aTexCoord}) in vec2 aTexCoord;


uniform mat4 uMvpMatrix;
uniform mat4 uModelMatrix;    // Model matrix
uniform mat4 uNormalMatrix;   // Transformation matrix of the normal

out vec3 vNormal;
out vec3 vPosition;
out vec2 vTexCoord;


void main() 
{
  gl_Position = uMvpMatrix * aPosition;

  // Calculate the vertex position in the world coordinate
  vPosition = vec3(uModelMatrix * aPosition);

  vNormal = normalize(vec3(uNormalMatrix * aNormal));
  vTexCoord = aTexCoord;
}`;

// Fragment shader program
const FSHADER_SOURCE =
`#version 300 es
precision highp float;

uniform vec3 uLightColor;     // Light color
uniform vec3 uLightPosition;  // Position of the light source
uniform vec3 uAmbientLight;   // Ambient light color


uniform sampler2D specularMap;


in vec3 vNormal;
in vec3 vPosition;
in vec2 vTexCoord;
out vec4 fColor;

void main() 
{
    vec2 dHdxy;
    vec3 bumpNormal;
    float bumpness = 1.0;
    
    fColor = vec4(0.5, 0.5, 1, 1);

    // Normalize the normal because it is interpolated and not 1.0 in length any more
    vec3 normal = normalize(vNormal);

    // Calculate the light direction and make its length 1.
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(uLightPosition - vPosition);

    // The dot product of the light direction and the orientation of a surface (the normal)
    float nDotL;
    nDotL = max(dot(lightDirection, normal), 0.0);

    // Calculate the final color from diffuse reflection and ambient reflection
    vec3 diffuse = uLightColor * fColor.rgb * nDotL;
    vec3 ambient = uAmbientLight * fColor.rgb;
    float specularFactor = texture(specularMap, vTexCoord).r; //Extracting the color information from the image

    bumpNormal = normal;
    vec3 specular = vec3(0.0);
    float shiness = 12.0;
    vec3 lightSpecular = vec3(1.0);

    vec3 v = normalize(-vPosition); // EyePosition
    vec3 r = reflect(-lightDirection, bumpNormal); // Reflect from the surface
    specular = lightSpecular * specularFactor * pow(dot(r, v), shiness);

    fColor = vec4( (diffuse + specular) + ambient, fColor.a); // Specular
}`;

function main() {
  const m4 = twgl.m4;
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
  if (!gl) { return alert('need webgl2'); }

  const prgInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE]);
  const verts = twgl.primitives.createSphereVertices(1, 40, 40);
  // calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each array
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
    aPosition: verts.position,
    aNormal: verts.normal,
    aTexCoord: verts.texcoord,
    indices: verts.indices,
  });
  
  const specularTex = twgl.createTexture(gl, {src: 'https://i.imgur.com/JlIJu5V.jpg'});

  function render(time) {
    twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);

    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer for each attribute
    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, prgInfo, bufferInfo);

    gl.useProgram(prgInfo.program);

    const fov = 60 * Math.PI / 180;
    const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    const near = 0.1;
    const far = 20.0;
    const mat = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, near, far);
    
    m4.translate(mat, [0, 0, -3], mat);
    
    const model = m4.rotationY(time / 1000);

    m4.multiply(mat, model, mat);

    // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniform
    twgl.setUniforms(prgInfo, {
      uMvpMatrix: mat,
      uModelMatrix: model,    // Model matrix
      uNormalMatrix: model,   // Transformation matrix of the normal
      uLightColor: [1, 1, 1],     // Light color
      uLightPosition: [2, 2, 10], // Position of the light source
      uAmbientLight: [0, 0, 0],   // Ambient light color
      specularMap: specularTex,
    });

    // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
    
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
main();
```

```css
body { margin: 0 }
canvas { display: block; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Then you should argably not use lots of boolean conditionals on your shader. Either make different shaders for find a way to do it without the booleans. So for example we don't need

```
uniform sampler2D earth_disp;
uniform sampler2D moon_disp;

uniform sampler2D sun_color;
uniform sampler2D earth_color;
uniform sampler2D moon_color;

uniform sampler2D earth_bump;
uniform sampler2D moon_bump;

uniform bool uIsSun;
uniform bool uIsEarth;
uniform bool uIsMoon;
```

we can just have

```
uniform sampler2D displacementMap;
uniform sampler2D surfaceColor;
uniform sampler2D bumpMap;
```

Then we can set the `displacementMap` and the `bumpMap` to a single pixel 0,0,0,0 texture and there will be no displacement and no bump.

As for different lighting for sun, given the sun uses neither the bump map nor the displacement map nor even lighting at all it would arguably be better to use a different shader but, we can also just add a `maxDot` value like this

```
uniform float maxDot;

...

   nDotL = max(dot(lightDirection, normal), maxDot)
```

If `maxDot` is zero we'll get a normal dot product. If `maxDot` is one we get no lighting.

```js
"use strict";
const loc_aPosition = 3;
const loc_aNormal = 5;
const loc_aTexture = 7;
const VSHADER_SOURCE =
`#version 300 es
layout(location=${loc_aPosition}) in vec4 aPosition;
layout(location=${loc_aNormal}) in vec3 aNormal;
layout(location=${loc_aTexture}) in vec2 aTexCoord;


uniform mat4 uMvpMatrix;
uniform mat4 uModelMatrix;    // Model matrix
uniform mat4 uNormalMatrix;   // Transformation matrix of the normal

uniform sampler2D displacementMap;

out vec2 vTexCoord;
out vec3 vNormal;
out vec3 vPosition;

void main() 
{

  float disp;

  disp = texture(displacementMap, aTexCoord).r; 
  vec4 displace = aPosition;

  float displaceFactor = 0.1;
  float displaceBias = 0.0;

  displace.xyz += (displaceFactor * disp - displaceBias) * aNormal;
  gl_Position = uMvpMatrix * displace;

  // Calculate the vertex position in the world coordinate
  vPosition = vec3(uModelMatrix * aPosition);

  vNormal = normalize(mat3(uNormalMatrix) * aNormal);
  vTexCoord = aTexCoord;

}`;

// Fragment shader program
const FSHADER_SOURCE =
`#version 300 es
precision highp float;

uniform vec3 uLightColor;     // Light color
uniform vec3 uLightPosition;  // Position of the light source
uniform vec3 uAmbientLight;   // Ambient light color

uniform sampler2D surfaceColor;
uniform sampler2D bumpMap;
uniform sampler2D specularMap;

uniform float maxDot;

in vec3 vNormal;
in vec3 vPosition;
in vec2 vTexCoord;
out vec4 fColor;


vec2 dHdxy_fwd(sampler2D bumpMap, vec2 UV, float bumpScale)
{
    vec2 dSTdx  = dFdx( UV );
        vec2 dSTdy  = dFdy( UV );
        float Hll   = bumpScale * texture( bumpMap, UV ).x;
        float dBx   = bumpScale * texture( bumpMap, UV + dSTdx ).x - Hll;
        float dBy   = bumpScale * texture( bumpMap, UV + dSTdy ).x - Hll;
        return vec2( dBx, dBy );
}

vec3 pertubNormalArb(vec3 surf_pos, vec3 surf_norm, vec2 dHdxy)
{
    vec3 vSigmaX = vec3( dFdx( surf_pos.x ), dFdx( surf_pos.y ), dFdx( surf_pos.z ) );
        vec3 vSigmaY = vec3( dFdy( surf_pos.x ), dFdy( surf_pos.y ), dFdy( surf_pos.z ) );
        vec3 vN = surf_norm;        // normalized
        vec3 R1 = cross( vSigmaY, vN );
        vec3 R2 = cross( vN, vSigmaX );
        float fDet = dot( vSigmaX, R1 );
        fDet *= ( float( gl_FrontFacing ) * 2.0 - 1.0 );
        vec3 vGrad = sign( fDet ) * ( dHdxy.x * R1 + dHdxy.y * R2 );
        return normalize( abs( fDet ) * surf_norm - vGrad );
}



void main() 
{
    vec2 dHdxy;
    vec3 bumpNormal;
    float bumpness = 1.0;
    fColor = texture(surfaceColor, vTexCoord);
    dHdxy = dHdxy_fwd(bumpMap, vTexCoord, bumpness);

    // Normalize the normal because it is interpolated and not 1.0 in length any more
    vec3 normal = normalize(vNormal);

    // Calculate the light direction and make its length 1.
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(uLightPosition - vPosition);

    // The dot product of the light direction and the orientation of a surface (the normal)
    float nDotL;
    nDotL = max(dot(lightDirection, normal), maxDot);



    // Calculate the final color from diffuse reflection and ambient reflection
    vec3 diffuse = uLightColor * fColor.rgb * nDotL;
    vec3 ambient = uAmbientLight * fColor.rgb;
    float specularFactor = texture(specularMap, vTexCoord).r; //Extracting the color information from the image




    vec3 diffuseBump;
    bumpNormal = pertubNormalArb(vPosition, normal, dHdxy);
    diffuseBump = min(diffuse + dot(bumpNormal, lightDirection), 1.1);

    vec3 specular = vec3(0.0);
    float shiness = 12.0;
    vec3 lightSpecular = vec3(1.0);

    vec3 v = normalize(-vPosition); // EyePosition
    vec3 r = reflect(-lightDirection, bumpNormal); // Reflect from the surface
    specular = lightSpecular * specularFactor * pow(dot(r, v), shiness);

    //Update Final Color
    fColor = vec4( (diffuse * diffuseBump + specular) + ambient, fColor.a); // Specular
}`;

function main() {
  const m4 = twgl.m4;
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl2');
  if (!gl) { return alert('need webgl2'); }

  const prgInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [VSHADER_SOURCE, FSHADER_SOURCE]);
  const verts = twgl.primitives.createSphereVertices(1, 40, 40);
  // calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each array
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
    aPosition: verts.position,
    aNormal: verts.normal,
    aTexCoord: verts.texcoord,
    indices: verts.indices,
  });
  
  const textures = twgl.createTextures(gl, {
    zero: { src: new Uint8Array([0, 0, 0, 0])},
    earthSpecular: { src: 'https://i.imgur.com/JlIJu5V.jpg' },
    earthColor: { src: 'https://i.imgur.com/eCpD7bM.jpg' },
    earthBump: { src: 'https://i.imgur.com/LzFNOP8.jpg' },
    sunColor: { src: 'https://i.imgur.com/gl8zBLI.jpg', },
    moonColor: { src: 'https://i.imgur.com/oLiU4fm.jpg', },
    moonBump: { src: 'https://i.imgur.com/bDnjW8C.jpg', },
  });
  
  function render(time) {
    // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer for each attribute
    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, prgInfo, bufferInfo);

    twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);

    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

    gl.useProgram(prgInfo.program);

    const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    const fov = 60 * Math.PI / 180 / aspect;
    const near = 0.1;
    const far = 20.0;
    const viewProjection = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, near, far);
    m4.translate(viewProjection, [0, 0, -6], viewProjection);

    draw([0, 0, 0], {
       displacementMap: textures.earthBump,
       bumpMap: textures.earthBump,
       surfaceColor: textures.earthColor,
       specularMap: textures.earthSpecular,
       maxDot: 0,
       uAmbientLight: [0, 0, 0],
     });
    draw([-2.2, 0, 0], {
       displacementMap: textures.zero,
       bumpMap: textures.zero,
       surfaceColor: textures.sunColor,
       specularMap: textures.zero,
       maxDot: 1,
       uAmbientLight: [0, 0, 0],
     });
    draw([2.2, 0, 0], {
       displacementMap: textures.moonBump,
       bumpMap: textures.moonBump,
       surfaceColor: textures.moonColor,
       specularMap: textures.zero,
       maxDot: 0,
       uAmbientLight: [0, 0, 0],
     });

    function draw(translation, uniforms) {
       const model = m4.translation(translation);
       m4.rotateY(model, time / 1000, model);

      // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniform
      twgl.setUniforms(prgInfo, {
        uMvpMatrix: m4.multiply(viewProjection, model),
        uModelMatrix: model,    // Model matrix
        uNormalMatrix: m4.transpose(m4.inverse(model)),   // Transformation matrix of the normal
        uLightColor: [1, 1, 1],     // Light color
        uLightPosition: [2, 2, 10], // Position of the light source
        uAmbientLight: [1, 0, 0],   // Ambient light color
      });
      twgl.setUniforms(prgInfo, uniforms);

      // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
      twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
main();
```

```css
body { margin: 0 }
canvas { display: block; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

As for the displacement, displacement only works on vertices so you need a lot of vertices in your sphere to be able to see any displacement

As well there was an bug related to displacement. You're passing in normals as vec4 and this line

```
displace += (displaceFactor * disp - displaceBias) * aNormal;
```

Ends up adding a vec4 displacement.  In other words let's say you started with an `a_Position` of `vec4(1,0,0,1)` which would be on the left side of the sphere. `aNormal` because you declared it as a `vec4` is probably `vec4(1,0,0,1)` as well. Assuming you're actually passing it vec3 normal data via attributes from your buffer the default value for W is 1. Let's assume `disp` is 1, `displaceFactor` is 2 and `displaceBias` is 0.5 which is what you had. You end up wioth

```
displace = vec4(1,0,0,1) + (2 * 1 + 0.5) * vec4(1,0,0,1)
displace = vec4(1,0,0,1) + (1.5) * vec4(1,0,0,1)
displace = vec4(1,0,0,1) + vec4(1.5,0,0,1.5)
displace = vec4(2.5,0,0,2.5)
```

But you don't want W to be 2.5. One fix is to just use the xyz part of the normal.

```
displace.xyz += (displaceFactor * disp - displaceBias) * aNormal.xyz;
```

The more normal fix would be to only declare the normal attribute as vec3

```
in vec3 aNormal;

displace.xyz += (displaceFactor * disp - displaceBias) * aNormal;
```

In my example above the spheres are only radius = 1 so we only want adjust this displacement a little. I set `displaceFactor` to 0.1 and `displaceBias` to 0.

Comment: Thank you again sir! sorry for that nasty shader codes.. If I could switch the shaders without any problems, it would be much better codes

Comment: Switching shaders is easy. It's one comand `gl.useProgram(shaderProgramToUse)`. You need to keep track of uniforms for each shader but that's pretty trival. Maybe you could write some [small helper functions](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-less-code-more-fun.html)

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't have to multiply w value.. and there was another problem that I fixed by my own. This line `float disp` to `vec3 disp` and I extracted rgb information from the texture, since it has only black and white
 `disp = texture(earth_disp, aTexCoord).r;` to `disp = texture(earth_disp, aTexCoord).rgb`